# Kotlin mutableList() returned from Map::getOrElse does not expose add()

Tags: kotlin

I have

```
data class Person(var name: String, var hobbies: List<String>)

val people = mutableListOf(
        Person("joe", asList("biking", "baking")),
        Person("jane", asList("baking")),
        Person("jack", asList("painting"))
)
val map = mutableMapOf<String, List<String>>()

for ((name, hobbies) in people) {

    for (hobby in hobbies) {

        var peopleWithThisHobby = map.getOrElse(hobby, { mutableListOf() })
        peopleWithThisHobby.plus(name)
        map[hobby] = peopleWithThisHobby
    }
}

println(map)
```

At line `peopleWithThisHobby.plus(name)`, IntelliJ auto complete does not give me the `add()` method.

I have to instead use:

```
var peopleWithThisHobby = map.getOrElse(hobby, { mutableListOf() })
peopleWithThisHobby = peopleWithThisHobby.plus(name)
map[hobby] = peopleWithThisHobby
```

What gives? IS this by design? What's happening to the `mutableList()` being returned from within the `getOrElse` call?

I'm using Kotlin plugin version : 1.1.3-eap-85-IJ2017.2-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because your map definition has a `List` instead of `MutableList` as value. Change it to `MutableList` and it'll work.

```
val map = mutableMapOf<String, List<String>>()
```

Change the above to:

```
val map = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>()
```